# How to put angular material stepper in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to put **angular material stepper** like this example!
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

I installed angular material and imported the stepper component !

```
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
```

copy/paste all the code from https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview
the navigator shows blank page!! all the other components are removed

could anyone tell me the reason plz!!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console, also try restarting npm

Comment: Can you share the your code via `Stackblitz` or `Codesandbox` ?

Comment: Thanks I fixed it, I need to import  ReactiveFormsModule